# Laravel Lumen Logging gives A facade root has not been set

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have set up the basic example of Laravel lumen with `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen demo`. I am using Lumen version 8.

My .env file looks like

```
APP_NAME=Lumen
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mysql
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
```

I have created a controller `TrackerController` and called it in `routes/web.php`.

```php
// /app/Http/Controllers/TrackerController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TrackerController extends Controller {
    public function index(Request $request) {
        Log::info('message');
        return 'ok';
    }
}
```

My `/app/routes/web.php` looks like

```php
<?php

$router->get('/','TrackerController@index');
```

I would like to add logging to stdout (so I can later pipe that data to Cloudwatch in AWS ElasticBeanstalk) and from what I understood, this is available out of the box, but I can't seem to be able to get it to work.

Whenever I execute `Log::info('message');` in a controller, I get a `A facade root has not been set.`.

Without `Log::info('message');` everything is working as intended.

[image]

Comment: did you uncomment `$app->withFacades()` in the `bootstrap/app.php` file?

Comment: That actually did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure to uncommment the `$app->withFacades()` line in your `bootstrap/app.php` file. This method sets the application container statically on the Facade class so that each facade can use the container to resolve its 'root' (what the facade is the static proxy for).